# How to make the second line of a TextView not indent

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Example of my problem is [here](https://gyazo.com/86d14f21338b434a531b6f6b9ec632ee) I have no line break in there but I was wondering if it is possible to move it over without actually putting in a line break. The message TextView is lined with the name one.

Comment: you will have to add label and value in one textview if you don't need the indentation. From observation of image you have 2 textview one for label and another for value..textview is nothing but a view with invisible rectangular boundary..hope this is clear

Comment: better you can achieve using two textviews

Comment: I know that what/how a TextView works I have two textviews in use right now, one is for a message, how do I make it so if I indent the message it doesn't indent the next break.